# Params url do not execute get method form server

Tags: angular, typescript

I have very strange problem. 
I have component `ProductListItemsComponent`, In `ngOnInit` I execute the method `getCategoryFromServer` and `getProductList()`. This is look like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productsService.getCategoryFromServer();
  this.getProductList();
}
```

Method `getCategoryFromServer` is  in my service  `ProductsService` :

```
getCategoryFromServer() {
  this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category: CategoryModel[]) => {
    this.categoryModule = category;
    this.cateogoryChange.next(this.categoryModule.slice())
  })
}
```

Method `getProductList()` in  my component and look like this:

```
getProductList() {
  this.subscription = this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.categoryName = params['category'];
      this.singleProducts = this.productsService.getListOfProduct(this.categoryName);
    })
}
```

Problem is because start executing `getCategoryFromServer` and skip execution, and executed `getProductList` and after that execute `getCategoryFromServer`. But I need to first execute `getCategoryFromServer` and after that `getCategoryFromServer`.

Comment: Not clear what're u asking for.

Comment: I asking way skip `getCategoryFromServer ` and execute after `getProductList`.

Comment: Obviously problem is in the subscription in the `getCategoryFromServer ` that execute last.

Comment: You can wrap your getCategoryFromServer call in another Observable / Subjec t / BehaviorSubject or Promise to remove the asynchronicity of the `this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory()` call. I've added an answer for the Promise solution below. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're talking about the async of observables here. An easy solution for this behavior would be to wrap your `ProductsService` call `getCategoryFromServer()` in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
getCategoryFromServer(): Promise<CategoryModel[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe(
            (category: CategoryModel[]) => {
                this.categoryModule = category;
                this.cateogoryChange.next(this.categoryModule.slice());
                resolve(this.categoryModule.slice());
            },
            (error) => reject(error)
        );
    });
}
```

Here you see I've wrapped our original call in a promise, now you can also see if the subscribe was successful we call the resolver and pass back the data *(you don't have to do this, you can pass nothing back and things will work the same)* As well I've added error handling in your subscribe to reject the promise if something happens in your subscribe.

To use this in your ngInit it would look something like this now.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategoryFromServer().then((cat: CategoryModel[]) => {
        this.getProductList();
    }).catch( (reason: any) => {
        // error handling here
    });
}
```

Now you've successfully made a way to know that your async calls have finished and to run your `getProductList()` method.

Comment: Your welcome @KinJong please don't forget to mark answers on your stack questions :) and good luck with your project !